# To see all command line on output window while compiling

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation

I want to see all commands while building/releasing on the output window.
When I build my app I only see this:

```
------ Build started: Project: CemKutuphane, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  CemKutuphane -> D:\Projects\Test\CemKutuphane\CemKutuphane\bin\Debug\CemKutuphane.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

There is no csc.exe args in these lines. But visual studio ide is running behind of this.
Is there any way to see the all commands?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

dknaack's answer is correct so I'll repeat it in its entirity until he un-deletes it:

> You can set the verbosity level on
>
> **Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project
>   build output verbosity**

I've tried this and found that setting the logging to "Normal" or above showed the `csc.exe` command line being executed, like this:

```
1>CoreCompile:
1>  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:2008,1701,1702 ...
```

Note that you might need to **Clean** the project beforehand in order to see this - if the project is already up-to-date then MSBuild will skip several tasks.

Comment: When I built solution with setted `Normal` to `MsBuild project build output verbosity` I got this output: `------ Build started: Project: CemKutuphane, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Build started 26.01.2012 12:06:38.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  CemKutuphane -> D:\Projects\Test\CemKutuphane\CemKutuphane\bin\Debug\CemKutuphane.dll

Build succeeded.

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.07
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: This does not output the command being executed in VS 2017.  Specify the version of VS that this fixes in this question and let's move on please.

Comment: Set the verbosity to Detailed on VS2017 and above. It will use CL.exe instead

Comment: This doesn't work for VS2017 or higher versions.