# Is there a way to get the build command line used by Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, csc, vbc

I want to do a build from the command line, but I'd like to get the exact command line syntax from Visual Studio (2012), so that I don't have to manually figure out all of the flags, imports, and other parameters.

Is there a way to get Visual Studio to display this information?

Comment: Doesn't it show up in the Output window?

Comment: The build output does, warnings, errors, etc., but not the full command line used.  Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: It does but only with the right configuration. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016111/to-see-all-command-line-on-output-window-while-compiling

Comment: Ah, that worked!  If you post that link as an answer (ideally pasting the relevant part of the answer), I'll accept it as the answer to this question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

When you build a project or solution in Visual Studio, the entire command line used to run the compiler (csc.exe, including switches and parameters) is displayed in the Output window. If you don't see it there, check the Verbosity level by going to:

**Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity**

(You may need to choose "Show all settings")
[image: options in toolbar -- finding projects and solution in options]

It has to be set to "Normal" or higher. Check this question and answer for more details:

[To see all command line on output window while compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016111/to-see-all-command-line-on-output-window-while-compiling)

Comment: Sorry, guys, but I'm working with Visual Studio 2017 and I don't see the "Show all settings" checkbox, and obviously I don't see the command, even while having "Detailed" or "Diagnostic" verbosity. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dominique, The show all is not there, but the two options on the right are there.

Comment: This answer is invalid for Visual Studio 2017 or higher @Dominique is correct.
These suggestions don't work.

Answer (score 19):

I don't have enough reputation to comment acfrancis's answer, so I just post this simple answer:
In Visual Studio 2017, following acfrancis's answer, but set two option to `Detailed`:
[image]
and then copy the output, search `cl.exe` and `link.exe`(Well a lot of lines, In this case 730 lines, I can't fint both without search), you can find something like this:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The output window on verbose mode produces a lot of text. If you are interested in compilation and linking flags there is an easier way.

Just check your project configuration properties, C/C++ -> Command Line and Linker -> Command Line

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't show all the options used, such as <AdditionalOptions>...</AdditionalOptions> that may be specified in .props files within the solution, whereas the technique above of getting detailed MSBuild information will include such options