# See the C++ compiler and linker command-line args in VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 for C++ development, and having trouble setting some things up via the IDE, e.g., stackcommit.

What I would really like to see is just how the IDE is invoking the compiler/linker.

I can't find any such option under the View menu and wondered if anyone has found a way to do this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Right click project in Solution Explorer >> Properties >> C/C++ >> Command Line
- Right click project in Solution Explorer >> Properties >> Linker >> Command Line

Here you can see the All Options generated from all the Configuration Properties and you can add Additional Options if you so wish to.

Comment: Although stack commit can be found simply under Linker >> System (and OP probably wants stack *reserve*, not stack commit)

Comment: The command line you see here may be incomplete if you include projects via NuGet for example. This is because the added NuGet packages can modify the compile and link dependencies via their own `.targets` files. To see the actual compile or link commands used during the build process you need to increase the MSBuild project build output verbosity to `Detailed` or above as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/57968430/1843329