# LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_python27-vc142-mt-x64-1_71.lib' while boost_python version is 1.72

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, cmake, boost-python

I'm using cmake and Visual Studio 2019 to build my project. My boost version is 1.72 and I generated file `libboost_python27-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib` in directory `boost_1_72_0\stage\lib` with `b2.exe`.

I generated `.sln` file with cmake. Then I build the project in Visual Studio 2019. However,
it ended up with an error `LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_python27-vc142-mt-x64-1_71.lib'`

I really can't understand why it asks for libboost_python of version 1_71 instead of 1_72. I never introduced a version 1.71 request in any file. So how should it be like that? And how can I make it work?

My `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
project(framecore)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
message(STATUS "Configuring framecore")

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
# windows 
if(MSVC)
    # this although can be set by system variable Boost_INCLUDE_DIR etc
    set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR F:/boost_1_72_0)
    set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR F:/boost_1_72_0/stage/lib)
endif()
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS container)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS python27)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC src/core/*.cpp
        src/wraps/*.cpp)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_HEADER src/core/*.hpp
        src/core/*.h
        src/wraps/*.hpp
        src/wraps/*.h)

include_directories(src)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

message(STATUS "Boost Include path:  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "Python2.7 Include path: ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

if(MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB -DBOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H /bigobj")
    set(CMAKE_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_LINK_FLAGS} /verbose:lib")
endif()

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/output)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/output)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SRC_HEADER} ${SRC})

# set target library's prefix suffix
if(MSVC)
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".pyd")
endif()

message(STATUS "Boost_PYTHON27_LIBRARY:  ${Boost_PYTHON27_LIBRARY}")
# optimized;F:/boost_1_72_0/stage/lib/libboost_python27-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib;debug;F:/boost_1_72_0/stage/lib/libboost_python27-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.lib

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_PYTHON27_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PYTHON_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_CONTAINER_LIBRARY})
```

Comment: When you build, does it show the command line parameters getting passed to LINK.exe ? That will give all the hints about what library paths (`/L` option) are getting passed.

Comment: @selbie what do you mean by `/L` option? I tried to put `/L` to Linker-CommandLine-AddtionalOptions (`%(AdditionalOptions) /machine:x64 /verbose:lib /L`), but output said `/L` option is unrecognizable and ignored. verbose option gave these information: looking for `F:\boost_1_72_0\stage\lib\libboost_python27-vc142-mt-x64-1_72.lib:`, `C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib:`, `libboost_system...`, `libboost_container...`, `... kernel32 and 9more libs...`, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64\msvcprt.lib:`, THEN, error LNK1104 was reported

Comment: Sorry, I think I meant `/LIBPATH`, not `/L`. Anyway, turn on verbose build output using the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57968430/104458) then inspect the link.exe command line from the build output.

Comment: Oh I think I know the reason now. I wrongly included a folder where there is a folder called boost with some header files in it. Maybe there some file was included and made a dependency on boost 1.71...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the reason now. There is another boost directory with some header files in my project folder. I wrongly included the boost directory and made a dependency on boost 1.71....